# Regex for Integer or Decimal(10,2) in C#

Tags: c#, regex, oracle, integer, decimal

I am inserting data in Oracle through C# Windows Form.

I have a textbox which takes price (`textbox.Text` should be validated for the regex before inserting data in DB). The column for this data is *Decimal(10,2)* in Oracle. So, it should accept `1,2`, `10,67`,.. and `10.2`, `2345.78`, `12345678.12`.

I tried the following regex:

```
string regex = @"^[+]?(?:\d{0,8}(?:\.\d{0,2})?|\.\d{1,8})$";
```

But this is not working for my requirements.
Can anyone help to suggest what is wrong in the regex and how this can be achieved?

Comment: [Decimal.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.decimal.parse?view=net-5.0). Or [VALIDATE_CONVERSION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD). Do not reinvent parsing

Comment: Do you want to accept a price like 8.328 (which Oracle will round to 8.33), or do you want to reject anything with more than two decimals? Also, do you need to allow sign (plus or minus)? If not, what's the `[+]` doing in your attempt?

Comment: Why are you using a Regex? You have `Decimal.TryParse()` to validate the input. Truncate, if that's a real requirement.

Comment: You want to accept a , but in your regex there is no ,. You can use `^\+?\d{0,8}([,.]\d{0,2})?$`. But - as the others said - you should use TryParse. It supports locale settings. In some settings *13,400.10* is 13 400.10 but in German the , sign would be the decimal separator. In German locale setting *13.100,10* is 13 100.10.

Comment: @mathguy I dont want to accept more than 2 digits after decimal. Only plus sign can be allowed if user enters, though I can remove it too (to not accept). I have added [+] to accept positive integers or decimals if user enters it with +.

Comment: @Michael I dont want to accept , in my input. Only numbers like 10 ,  9 , 8 .. (integers) or decimal like 10.2, 10.22, 1000.22, 10000000.22 ...

Comment: I want to accept integers and decimals with a fixed precision and scale which is why I thought it would be easier through regex.

Comment: Like `^\+?[0-9]{1,8}(?:\.[0-9]{2})?$` ? https://regex101.com/r/QGg121/1

Comment: Do you want to allow prices like 34. (meaning 34, but allow a decimal point with no trailing decimals)? Do you want to allow prices like .48 meaning 0.48 but without the leading 0?

Comment: It's better to validate input where it appears: at the application side. Without call for the DBMS at all. For this you have C# with Decimal class and appropriate methods that allow you to work with real decimals, not strings that (in some culture) looks like decimals.

Comment: @mathguy I want to accept .48 but not 34. (without digits after decimal point).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should work: `^\d{0,8}(\.\d{1,2})?$`

Comment: No, this is not working for Integers or decimal. Also, I guess d{1,10} can take 10 digits before decimal while it should take only upto 8 decimal as datatype is Decimal(10,2).

Comment: @userhmp just noted you wanted commas as well, and 8 digits, so I've edited my answer, it works for any use case you gave.

Comment: I dont want comma. I just want it to accept integers or Decimal with precision 10 and scale 2. It is not working with that type of values. Tried in online sites.

Comment: @userhmp in my original answer I added the extra backslashes because of python warnings, but after removing backslashes from my original regex it worked on online regex tester for c#. try the new edit

Comment: This can't be right. The decimal point is optional, so you are allowing integer values up to 10 digits. Also, what is the purpose of the outer-most parantheses?

Comment: @mathguy you're right, it was leftovers from changes i made till i understood OP intentions. Fixed.

Comment: @Daniel updated one is working for my situation. I also got to learn how this worked. Thanks.

Comment: @userhmp you're welcome :). when you get a correct, working solution for your question, you should mark it by clicking on the V sign at the **top left** of the answer. when you see a helpful question/answer in general, you should click on the **up arrow** at the top left, to mark that it was helpful. note: you might need specific amount of reputation in order to make some actions like **upvote**